# What type of multi-label method does sklearn's random forest classifier use?

Tags: python, random-forest, scikit-learn, multilabel

I have trained RandomForestClassifier on data with 3 labels. The label set Y looks like this:

```
Y = array([[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]])
```

I have some feature set X:

```
X = array([[13, 4, 2],
   [2, 2, 4],
   [7, 17, 1],
   [5, 2, 0],
   [4, 1, 12],
   [2, 3, 3]])
```

I run the algorithm as follows:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True,
                              max_depth=10,
                              max_features='sqrt',
                              random_state=1)

rfc.fit(X, Y)
```

Everything works beautifully, and I get classifications and probabilities to my heart's content. But I don't know exactly what I'm getting. Does the algorithm by default use binary relevance? Power set labeling? Classifier chain? I cannot find any documentation on this [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).

My main concern is this: am I capturing interactions between the different labels, or am I pretty much just training three independent random forests?

It doesn't seem to be the latter; I have verified that the model trained on a 1-dimensional label set does not match the results of the multi-label model. In other words, there are cases where the multi-label model predicts [1, 0, 0] but using only the first label for training the model results in a prediction of 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base estimator of `RandomForestClassifier` is `DecisionTreeClassifier`, which
indeed builds a single generalized model capable of processing output correlations.
To build a tree, it uses a multi-output splitting criteria computing average impurity
reduction across all the outputs. That is, a random forest averages a number of decision
tree classifiers predicting multiple labels.

To create multiple independent (identical) models, consider
[`MultiOutputClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html).
As for classifier chains, use [`ClassifierChain`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.ClassifierChain.html).

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#multi-output-problems

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In sum, RandomForestClassifier uses "power set labeling", treating each of the 8 possible label combinations from [0,0,0] to [1,1,1] as a distinct outcome... thus capturing interactions between the three labels.

Answer (score 0):

Given an input $x$, scikit-learn's random forest implementation estimates the probability of each class, as described in the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html). Class probabilities are computed for each tree as the frequency of class labels among training points in the same leaf node as $x$. The class probabilities are averaged across trees to produce a final distribution over classes. This distribution can be accessed using the `predict_proba()` and `predict_log_proba()` methods. To produce a point estimate, the `predict()` method predicts the class of $x$ as the class with the highest probability.